# Disable button when no option is selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an input type button (it can not be submit type because it triggers a secondary action inside a form) that I need to maintain disabled if no selection made on a previous dropdown selector. I have unsuccessfuly tried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911957/how-to-disable-button-if-i-select-no-in-dropdown-list), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207125/disable-button-from-option-select), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102464/disable-button-if-no-selected-value-in-dropdown), and some others...

here it is my form code :

```
echo "<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname' size='1' name='corpusname' required />
<option value=''>Select a corpus</option>";

// This query gives the other options from a database
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM corpus_info") or die(mysqli_error($db));
while($cpsmlg = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='".$cpsmlg['corpus']."'>".$cpsmlg['title']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>
<a id='theLink' target='_blank'>

// This is the button to be disabled
<input type='button' id='seedoc' class='seedoc' value='See doc' /></a>";
```

Comment: You need the help of js to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes, the things I've tried are js, you can check the links I add

Comment: `if no selection made on a previous dropdown selector.` where is that-one (previous drop-down selector)?

Comment: The one that starts `<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname'..`

Comment: Yes, one drop down and one button, if nothing selected on the dropdown, button disabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add an `onchange` event to the `select`.

```js
function enableButton()
{
    var selectelem = document.getElementById('corpusname');
    var btnelem = document.getElementById('seedoc');
    btnelem.disabled = !selectelem.value;
}
```

```html
<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname' size='1' name='corpusname' required onchange="enableButton()"/>
<option value=''>Select a corpus</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="seedoc" disabled value="Submit">
```

Comment: that way when he changes back to empty the button will remain enabled

Comment: Thanks, I could realize now that the problem I had was about quotes, as I'm under php I had to write it this way to work: `onchange=\"document.getElementById('seedoc').disabled=false;\"`

Comment: No. But before after selecting some item, btn got enabled. Then if you select `Select a corpus` it will be still be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet without the php part, the php part is still the same.

```js
function ValidateDropDwon(dd){
  var input = document.getElementById('seedoc')
  if(dd.value == '') input.disabled = true; else input.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname' size='1' name='corpusname' required onchange="ValidateDropDwon(this)">
     <option value=''>Select a corpus</option>
     <option value='test'>test</option>
</select>

<input type='submit' id='seedoc' class='seedoc' disabled value='See doc' />
```

Answer (score 0):

since you list `jQuery` I will use that here.

```
echo "<select class='corpusname' id='corpusname' size='1'
              name='corpusname' required onChange='enableButton()' />
      <option value=''>Select a corpus</option>";

// This query gives the other options from a database
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM corpus_info") or die(mysqli_error($db));
while($cpsmlg = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<option value='".$cpsmlg['corpus']."'>".$cpsmlg['title']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>

<a id='theLink' target='_blank'>

// This is the button to be disabled
<input type='button' id='seedoc' class='seedoc' disabled value='See doc' /></a>";
```

then some javascript on the page to accomplish the `onchange()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableButton(){
      $("#seedoc").prop('disabled', false);
    }
</script>
```

I would put in a check, `if corpusname = ''...` but it will not ever be changed back to a `''`, so `onChange()` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

***If You have Jquery Included , You Can use this (EASIEST)  :***

```
$('#corpusname').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#seedoc').attr('disabled','disabled'); //Disables if Values of Select Empty
    }else{
        $('#seedoc').removeAttr('disabled');  
    }
});
```